# Using aggregate function for seprate rows

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

There is a table with name jobs where for different department number salary is giving. Same department can have more than one job so the salary may vary. Now i want to solve this query:

"Find the average salaries for each department without displaying the respective department numbers."

Here i should use avg but how to use it so that i can get my result of each department no separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `GROUP BY` clause. If I understand your question correctly then something like this should do the trick.

`SELECT AVG(salary) FROM table_name GROUP BY department`